# Counters in XSLT

Tags: xslt

how to implement counter type functionality in xslt

Comment: You shouldn't. XSLT is for XML transformations, not for logic.

Comment: You typically would use recursion. Give a more concrete example of what you are trying to do and we will see how to solve it.

Comment: actually i'm using XSLT in sharepoint DVWP and have got grouping done based upon one column now i want to keep track how many elements i have in each group. i have to apply unique image on each of the group item based upon some logic. hence i can not use position() as well

Comment: This is not a real question. Please, post a real problem: source XML file (as minimal as possible), wanted result, how the results is related to the source XML (properties of the transformation). Then many people will be able to help.

Comment: This question is as general as "How to implement imperative counter type functionality in declarative paradigm". The general answer is passing the counter as parameter in recursion. But, because the power of XPath expression, sometimes this can be done ussing context node as a parameter for preceding calculations. Also, some specific task as numbering has specific instructions in XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT is based upon Functional programming hence you can not use counters you can try Recursions if it can be of your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to simulate counter functionality, but you have not specified any input or output format, so providing some general code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- TODO: Auto-generated template -->
        <xsl:call-template name="counter">
            <xsl:with-param name="start" select="1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="stop" select="10" />
            <xsl:with-param name="increment" select="1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="counter">
        <xsl:param name="start" />
        <xsl:param name="stop" />
        <xsl:param name="increment" />
        Value:<xsl:value-of select="$increment"/>
        <xsl:if test="$increment &lt; $stop">
                <xsl:call-template name="counter">
                <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$start" />
                <xsl:with-param name="stop" select="$stop" />
                <xsl:with-param name="increment" select="$increment+1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```